# Abstract with inheritor as field

Tags: c#, .net

I'm making a program with multiple types of binary trees in it. So I decided to make an abstract class, to avoid copying code over. But there is a problem, the nodes of each tree need to contain children that are the same type as the node itself. Is there any means to define this in the abstract, or should I just make different classes for each type after all?

```
public abstract class BinaryNodeAbstract<T>
{
    public T Value;
    public BinaryNodeAbstract<T> Left;
    public BinaryNodeAbstract<T> Right;
```

The way it is now, the nodes could be of any type BinaryNode. That is what needs to be avoided.

Comment: add `where T: BinaryNodeAbstract<T>`, but it may be just a partial solution

Comment: So what's wrong with your implementation? It looks just good.

Comment: What's wrong with what you've got? And does it even need to be abstract?

Comment: I just added a piece... The problem is that there are different types of BinaryNodes, but it needs to be the same node as the one that implemented it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should include the parent type too, to keep the inherited type on `Left` and `Right` (else you can't use the inherited type on the implementer):

```
public abstract class BinaryNodeAbstract<T, L> where L : BinaryNodeAbstract<T, L>
{
    public T Value;
    public L Left;
    public L Right;
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
public class BinaryNodeImplementation : BinaryNodeAbstract<int, BinaryNodeImplementation>
{
}
```

Comment: Awh man, that's mad. I'm trying it now, looks like it should work. Thanks.